# Is it correct to say "work underneath"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The much more common expression is to "work under," but I saw "work underneath" in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosalba_Carriera) and for some reason it bothered me:

> In return, the empress worked underneath her and received formal artistic training.

I know that some distinction between under and underneath can just come down to what sounds right to native English speakers as two words are extremely similar (talked about [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463480/difference-between-under-underneath-below-and-beneath/463944) on this site), but "underneath" does seem to be used more exclusively in a locational sense.

The site idioms.thefreedictionary.com has an entry for "work under" but not "work underneath." The Google tracker also puts the [usage of "work underneath"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20under%2C%20work%20underneath&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20under%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20underneath%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwork%20under%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20underneath%3B%2Cc0) basically always somewhere near zero. Is there a right and wrong answer or can two words be used interchangeably in this expression?

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: "Difference between “underneath” and “under” when we describe an action" https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56331/14666

Comment: See also: "Under the control or power of: *There was little freedom underneath the jackboot.*" at https://wikidiff.com/underneath/under HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work **under** someone (as say an apprentice) is more common but **underneath** is encountered and means the same:

**underneath**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/211859?redirectedFrom=underneath#eid)

> In subordination or subjection to; under the power or control of.

As in:

> 1600   Shakespeare Henry IV, Pt. 2 iv. iii. 10   Til these
>   rebels..Come vnderneath the yoke of gouernment.

and

*I have five people working under/underneath me in the firm.*